# Which pandas methods have engine_kwargs for numba support?

Tags: pandas, numba

[This pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#numba-jit-compilation) notes that `numba` can be used "*in select pandas methods*," and, "*Methods that support `engine="numba"` will also have an `engine_kwargs` keyword....*"

What are these select pandas methods?  Is there a list somewhere?

(Note that this is not trivial: The example provided on that page shows the argument being passed to `.apply()`, but `DataFrame.apply()` does not support it.  Is it `DataFrame.rolling`?  Nope.  In that example it is derived from `window.rolling`....)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an (hopefully) exhaustive list of pandas function that support `engine="numba"`.

Top level pandas functions:

- [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval)

Groupby operations (DataFrame and Series):

- [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html), [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html), <s>`median`</s>, [`var`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.var.html), [`std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.std.html), [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.min.html), [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html)
- [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)
- [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)
- <s>`apply`</s>

Rolling operations:

- [`pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html), [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html), [`median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.median.html), [`var`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.var.html), [`std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.std.html)
  , [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.min.html)
  , [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html)
- [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html)

Expanding operations

- [`pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.mean.html), [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.sum.html), [`median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.median.html), [`var`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.var.html), [`std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.std.html), [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.min.html), [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.max.html)
- [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html)

Exponential moving window (ewm) operations:

- [`pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow.mean.html), [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow.sum.html), [`var`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow.var.html), [`std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow.std.html), [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow.min.html), [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow.max.html)
- [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.ewm.ExponentialMovingWindow.apply.html)